# project building in eclipse but not from terminal/jenkins - using Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, jenkins, ant

I am using Ant to build my java project. Basically, the build file is the default `build.xml` that is created when you right click on project in eclipse and select `plug-in tools` > `create Ant build file`. This builds the project with a couple of eclipse plugin dependencies and creates a folder with all the **.class** files.

When I run my default `build.xml.` from eclipse, it's working fine. It creates the folder with .class files just like I want.

However, when I try to run it through my terminal like:

```
ant -buildfile build.xml
```

or even through jenkins for that matter, I get errors like:

```
[javac] .jenkins/workspace/..../UserExitImpl.java:87: error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
[javac]     @Override
[javac]      ^
[javac]   (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
```

And I get 100 such errors. It points to a different location every time but the error is the same. It says either annotations are not supported or generics are not supported.

**Changing the source code is not an option for me so the source code doesn't matter here, since it already works fine from eclipse**, which is suggested in many other StackOverflow answers.

Also, I tried checking **how to user -source 5 or higher using Ant**, but I found nothing.

How can I fix this?

[Here's my build.xml file.](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3737)

Thanks!

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<property name="javacSource" value="1.3"/>`

The error is pretty self explanatory.  You are using syntax that was introduced in Java 1.5, but telling ant to use 1.3.  Change the javacSource value in your build.xml to 1.5, remove the line altogether, or make the code compliant with 1.3.